# Subset dataframe on Axis 1 based on a condition for rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = DataFrame({'A':['Cat had a nap','Dog had puppies','Did you see a Donkey','kitten got angry','puppy was cute'],'Cat':[1,0,0,1,0],'Dog':[0,1,0,0,1]})


              A         Cat Dog
0   Cat had a nap        1  0
1   Dog had puppies      0  1
2   Did you see a Donkey 0  0
3   kitten got angry     1  0
4   puppy was cute       0  1
```

EDIT 1:
How can I map every row with a concatenated column names which have '1' in that row?

Expected Output:

```
             A         Cat Dog Category
0   Cat had a nap        1  0   Cat, Dog
1   Dog had puppies      0  1   Dog
2   Did you see a Donkey 0  0   NaN
3   kitten got angry     1  0   Cat, Dog
4   puppy was cute       0  1   Dog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) all values of DataFrame and check at least one `True` per rows of columns by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

For filter rows:

```
df = df[df.eq(1).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
                  A  Cat  Dog
0     Cat had a nap    1    0
1   Dog had puppies    0    1
3  kitten got angry    1    0
4    puppy was cute    0    1
```

For filter columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.eq(1).any()]
print (df)
   Cat  Dog
0    1    0
1    0    1
2    0    0
3    1    0
4    0    1
```

For filter columns and rows:

```
m = df.eq(1)
df = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), m.any()]
print (df)
   Cat  Dog
0    1    0
1    0    1
3    1    0
4    0    1
```

EDIT:

```
df['Category'] = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1]
print (df)
                      A  Cat  Dog Category
0         Cat had a nap    1    0      Cat
1       Dog had puppies    0    1      Dog
2  Did you see a Donkey    0    0         
3      kitten got angry    1    0      Cat
4        puppy was cute    0    1      Dog
```

Comment: If I have to do that for each row then?

Comment: Wdo you think first solution?

Comment: Sorry. I will edit my question. I need to map each row with a catenated column names in which the value is 1

Comment: @SharvariGc - Not sure if understand, what is expected output?